# How to make the master branch track?

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and was working in the master branch.  There was a consistent problem: `git push` (and `git push`) didn't work and gave long, uninterpretable error message.  Through trial-and-error, I found `git push origin master` did the push correctly. But now I've noticed something odd:

```
$ git config push.default tracking
$ git push
fatal: The current branch master is not tracking anything.
```

WTF?  I thought if you cloned a repository, the master was automatically tracked.  Anyway, my real questions are

1. How am I supposed to create a clone so the branches are tracked?
2. What are the consequences (other than current) of *not* having tracking?
3. How do I fix the current situation, so that my branch does track the remote?

**EDIT**
My local repository was acting strangely in other ways; most notably: I couldn't create remote branches. I put it aside and made a fresh clone, and it's acting strangely in fresh ways.

First, `master` is tracking (yeah).  Second, I was able to make a remote branch, but it's odd.

```
Ratatouille $ git push origin origin:refs/heads/premium
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:gamecrush/Ratatouille.git
 * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> premium
Ratatouille $ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/premium
```

Ratatouille is the name of the remote repo, of course.  The strange point: what is that `->` there for?  It seems to be new and it doesn't show up for the old local repo or other clones of the remote.

But now branching and tracking work as advertised.

Comment: I need some coffee. I read this as "How to fix monster truck brakes?" and thought "there isn't even a stack exchange for that!" :-(

Comment: Right, I *also* need to fix the brakes on my monster truck. And I need a copy of the *Mister Brooks* script.

Comment: Related issue - I had a tracking branch stop tracking after a "git reset --hard" (not sure why) and Arrowmaster's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What is your `branch.autosetupmerge` set to? By default it should have setup the branch tracking when you cloned.

Try setting the upstream for the branch with this to make the branch track the remote.

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Comment: I have been playing around with it so it's *currently* true, but might very well have been false at the time the repo was cloned (although why I don't know).  Is there some way of showing what, if anything, a branch is tracking?

Comment: @Malvolio: Use `git remote show origin` to get a list of what branches are tracking in that remote. The `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` in your edited question looks normal to me.

Comment: @Arrowmaster -- first, thanks for the name of the command.  Second, it isn't normal in the literal sense: the other repos lack that -> thing.  The output of `show origin` is mostly helpful except for this: `HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):` (with master and my new branch listed).  My only theory: I have not done any new commits on either branch since creating the second branch, so if HEAD must point to a commit, not a branch, and the heads (uh, if that is the word) of the branches are same, then it can't tell what branch it is on.

Comment: @Malvolio: The `git push origin origin:refs/heads/premium` is likely the cause of this. I would try deleting the remote branch with `git push --delete refs/heads/premium` and seeing if that makes any difference in the remote show output. The cause of this is likely a typo where you put origin instead of master as the local branch name to push.

Comment: @Arrowmaster -- **not** a typo!  I was following the instructions at http://www.zorched.net/2008/04/14/start-a-new-branch-on-your-remote-git-repository/ .  Was the second *origin* supposed to be master?

Comment: @Malvolio: Yes it appears that page is incorrect. One of the comments corrects it to master.

Comment: @Arrowmaster -- [Augh](http://problemstosolve.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/charlie-brown-baseball-aaugh.jpg)

Comment: The `--set-upstream` flag is now deprecated. Prefer `--set-upstream-to` or `--track`

Answer (score 6):

An alternative: to set the master to track the remote, during your first push execute:

```
git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` will do the same as `--set-upstream`. After, run `git branch -vv` to see a list of branches including their tracking branches.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave.  Am I to understand that "upstream" is the reciprocal relationship of "track"?  That if A is upstream of B, B tracks A?  Maybe in Finnish...

Comment: Yes, I think that is a fair statement. My head starts to hurt if you think about an upstream branch tracking a downstream branch.

Answer (score 6):

Other alternative:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```